# How to redirect non www to www for angular (example.com to www.example.com)

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess, redirect

I know there are so many questions already been addressed, but I still couldn't find a good answer, particularly for angular. Someone please tell me how can I redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com` in `.htaccess`.

Currently my `.htaccess` looks like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

But its not redirecting

Comment: IMHO you don't have a single rule in your current .htaccess which deals with `non www` **to** `www` so it will not do it.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 please tell me that rule, thats the question

Comment: Have you tried the solutions from other questions?  If so, what didn't work about them.  Without that information, this question is just another request for the same thing.